# Importing any .d.ts results in runtime error

Tags: typescript

There's something simple in TypeScript I'm missing here...

Using Chrome to run my code, I have a working typescript environment and all of my other code/modules are working as expected.

When I import from a .d.ts, everything compiles with no errors/warnings, but I get a runtime error in Chrome, because the generated JavaScript is trying to import from a non-existing file.

```
import { doSomething } from "exampleJsLibrary";
```

which fails in the browser because TypeScript doesn't turn exampleJsLibrary.d.ts into a JS file.

I'm targeting es5, using es6 module output, and using tsc to build (no webpack/browserify tools), ts 2.7.2.

*Full example:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script>
            var exampleJsLibrary = (function() {
                return {
                    doSomething: function(x) { return x + 1 }
                }
            })()
    </script>
    <script type="module" src="./built/myCode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
// exampleJsLibrary.d.ts
export const doSomething(x: number): number;
export as namespace exampleJsLibrary;


// myCode.ts
import { doSomething } from "./exampleJsLibrary";
function test() {
    console.log(doSomething(3));
}

// tsconfig.json
...
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "es5", "es2015.iterable", "es2015"],
        "outDir": "built",
        "module": "es6"
...
```

The failure occurs because the generated code for myCode.js
still has the line `import { doSomething } from "./exampleJsLibrary"`,
which causes a runtime error because there is no exampleJsLibrary or exampleJsLibrary.js.
If I replace that line in the generated JS with `var doSomething = exampleJsLibrary.doSomething`, everything works.

How do you import from a .d.ts?

Comment: Importing a `d.ts` file is typically done with a [triple slash directive](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html), so if all you're imporing are the types, try adding a line `/// <reference path="./exampleJsLibrary" />` (with the correct relative path) instead of using the import syntax. Making sure whatever you use exists at runtime is a different matter however.

Comment: From your example, it looks like `exampleJsLibrary` is just declared as a global in a script tag--is it that way in the actual code too?

Comment: In the full project, it's included from a JavaScript file that creates a global, the effect is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.d.ts` [declaration files](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/ambient/d.ts.html) just contain type declarations, not the actual code. (They're like header files in C/C++, if you happen to be familiar with that.) You'll need to include the actual library code in your project and either import it or have it defined globally to make it work at runtime.

In your case, since the library code is included on the page as a global, you don't need to use `import`. Instead you can just say:

```
const doSomething = exampleJsLibrary.doSomething
```

If the compiler complains that `exampleJsLibrary` is not defined, the simplest fix is to add this at the top of your file (use the actual relative path to the .d.ts):

```
/// <reference path="path/to/exampleJsLibrary" />
```

(Note that the approach is different if your package is included from npm, which is pretty common.)

Comment: Yes, the actual code is available at runtime. It's a JavaScript object in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks! Updated. Let me know if anything is unclear or you start getting compiler errors--if so, that probably means the declaration file incorrectly defines the library as a module rather than a global.

Comment: Using /// <reference types="nameOfLibrary" /> seems to solve everything.